# Make [qstylesheet] a synonym of [qss]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [qstylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qstylesheet) tag is a clear synonym of the [qss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qss) tag, which already also has a [qt-stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-stylesheet) synonym. QSS stands for [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html), so perhaps the tag should also be renamed to [qstylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qstylesheets) and/or perhaps [qtstylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtstylesheets) / [qt-style-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-style-sheets).

Note there is no such thing as a QStyleSheet class in the Qt Toolkit (which the [qstylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qstylesheet) tag might suggest there is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approved the synonym which you created on Oct 26th. The [qstylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qstylesheet) tag wiki made this quite clear:

> Qt Style Sheets (part of the Qt framework) are a powerful mechanism that allows you to customize the appearance of widgets, in addition to what is already possible by subclassing QStyle. The concepts, terminology, and syntax of Qt Style Sheets are heavily inspired by HTML Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) but adapted to the world of widgets.

I then renamed the tag, as you had requested to [qtstylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtstylesheets), and added the other variants as synonyms.

Comment: For reference, this quote was taken from https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html